# Spring boot Could not resolve placeholder application.yml

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea, yaml

i'm new in spring and i have a trouble with it.
When i run my application with IntelliJ Idea everything works perfect, but when i compile it to a .jar application this give me this error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'jwt.secret' in value "${jwt.secret}"`

This is my `application.yml` located at `src/main/resources`

```
#Config Application
jwt:
  header: Authorization
  secret: mySecret
  expiration: 604800
  route:
    authentication:
      path: auth
      refresh: refresh
      token: check
```

When i change my to this it works perfect.

```
//    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    @Value("mySecret")
    private String secret;
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Note: i'm using MAVEN

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>test-app</name>
    <description>Test</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <jjwt.version>0.7.0</jjwt.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.mobile</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-mobile-device</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: How are you compiling? Are you using maven? Is this a spring boot application?

Comment: Try this,

    @ConfigurationProperties("jwt")
    public class CustomCacheConfiguration {

        @Value("${jwt.secret}")
        private String secret;

        ...
    }

Comment: I'm using maven

Comment: @AndyAlonzo post your `pom.xml`

Comment: pom.xml posted :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My bad i was building with Intellij Idea.
Build using this command:

```
./mvnw clean package
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;

env.getProperty("jwt.secret")
```

you can try!

Comment: use application.properties  try it ?

Answer (score -5):

You have a tiny mistake there.
Look at your application.yml:

```
 jwt:
  header: Authorization
  secret: mySecret
```

The property name is "secret" and not "mySecret". You accidentally bind to the value instead of the property name. Simply replace:

```
@Value("mySecret")
```

by this:

```
@Value("secret")
```

Your error message however indicates that you used the commented out "jws.secret". Please keep in mind that if you use a prefix (e.g. "jws") then you can refer to that property by "secret" only.

Comment: This is highly misleading as you are using constant and not expression. E.g. missing ${...}.